# Using react router. How can you redirect to a component and set the initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am iterating through an array of objects in my react component and each iteration needs to display a button that will redirect to another component and set the initial state of that component with data from the component with the redirect button.

this is the component I am redirecting to

```
const Member = (props) => {  
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
//  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);


  useEffect(async()=>{
    if (props.location.state && props.location.state.pro) {
      setUser(props.location.state.pro)
      console.log(user)
    }
 }, [props.location.state])
```

This is the component I am redirecting from

```
        {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
          return <tr key={index}>

<Link to={{
    pathname: "/member",
    state: {
      pro: p.publisher
    }
  }} 
>
     <button type="button">
          Click Me!
     </button>
 </Link>
        </tr>})}
```

The data I want to pass to the new component renders in the original component but it doesn't render in the redirected component or even set it as the 'user' state as it does not console.log(user)

Comment: If you are using you state in multiple components you should use contextAPI or redux, something similar. Or you could send params in the querystring with react router `<Route path="/mypath/:my/:variables/:toget/:in/:next/:component" component={MyComponent} />`

Then use the useParams hook from react-router-dom
`const {my,variables,toget,in,next,component} = useParams();`